# Presto datatype Mismatch Issue In Hive ORC Table

Tags: hive, hiveql, presto, presto-jdbc

I am trying to query my hive orc table by presto ,In Hive its working Fine.In prestro I am able to access all the column except lowrange  It's showing Below Erroe

```
error : Query 20220322_135856_00076_a33ec failed: Error opening Hive split hdfs://.....filename.orc 
(offset=0, length=24216): Malformed ORC file. Cannot read SQL type varchar from ORC stream .lowrange 
 of type LONG [hdfs://.....filename.orc.orc]
```

I have set below property in presto before starting the query:

```
set hive1.orc.use-column-names=true
```

where hive1 is my catalog name.

I have also tried to change Hive tables datatype for this column as Double/BigInt,Int But Nothing Worked.

Can someone help me to resolve the error.

Table Description:

```
+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--+
|           col_name            |                        data_type                        |        comment        |
+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--+
| # col_name                    | data_type                                               | comment               |
|                               | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
| lowrange                      | string                                                  |                       |
| type                          | string                                                  |                       |
| processed_date                | string                                                  |                       |
|                               | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
| # Partition Information       | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
| # col_name                    | data_type                                               | comment               |
|                               | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
| type                          | string                                                  |                       |
|                               | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
| # Detailed Table Information  | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
| Database:                     | test                                                    | NULL                  |
| Owner:                        | hdfs                                                    | NULL                  |
| CreateTime:                   | Tue Mar 22 08:28:49 UTC 2022                            | NULL                  |
| LastAccessTime:               | UNKNOWN                                                 | NULL                  |
| Protect Mode:                 | None                                                    | NULL                  |
| Retention:                    | 0                                                       | NULL                  |
| Location:                     | hdfs://......../user/hdfs/test/  | NULL                  |
| Table Type:                   | EXTERNAL_TABLE                                          | NULL                  |
| Table Parameters:             | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
|                               | EXTERNAL                                                | TRUE                  |
|                               | skip.header.line.count                                  | 1                     |
|                               | transient_lastDdlTime                                   | 1647937729            |
|                               | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
| # Storage Information         | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
| SerDe Library:                | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde               | NULL                  |
| InputFormat:                  | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat         | NULL                  |
| OutputFormat:                 | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat        | NULL                  |
| Compressed:                   | No                                                      | NULL                  |
| Num Buckets:                  | -1                                                      | NULL                  |
| Bucket Columns:               | []                                                      | NULL                  |
| Sort Columns:                 | []                                                      | NULL                  |
| Storage Desc Params:          | NULL                                                    | NULL                  |
|                               | field.delim                                             | ,                     |
|                               | serialization.format                                    | ,                     |
+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--+

Sample Data:

lowrange              type    processed_date

1234567890001212      01        20220323
1234567890001213      01        20220323
```

Table Create Statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(                       
`lowrange` string,                                                                                
`processed_date` string)                                  
PARTITIONED BY (                                            
`type` string)                                     
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED                                        
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','                                  
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                       
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'         
OUTPUTFORMAT                                                
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'        
LOCATION                                                    
'hdfs://......./user/hdfs/test'  
TBLPROPERTIES (                                             
   'skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

Update: I dropped the existing Table and created new table with  datatype from String to BigINt in hive table and able to select data from Table but When I am trying to perform lpad operation its again showing same issue.

```
Logic I want to apply on Field : lpad(lowrange ,13,'9')

Error: Unexpected parameters (bigint, integer, varchar(1)) for 
function lpad. Expected: lpad(varchar(x), bigint, varchar(y))
```

then I tried to cast bigint to varchar using Below query:

```
Updated Logic : lpad(cast(lowrange as varchar),13,'9'))

Error: 
Malformed ORC file. Cannot read SQL type bigint 
from ORC stream .lowrange of type STRING
```

Comment: can you pls add table definition?

Comment: can you try `lpad(cast(lowrange as string),13,'9'))` ? varchar type normally need a length - so use a string instead.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Executing In presto so used varchar.
it worked now. Actually I had 2 files for the same table. when I checked the orc file schema so dataType was different in both the table for this column. That's by it was showing issue. I have sync the datatype and loaded data in new table and its woking now.
thanks a lot for help.

Comment: can i add this as a solution then?